# Trying to script the install of qemue agent on cloud-int VM

Tags: qemu, linux-kvm, proxmox

I am currently using Proxmox to deploy some VMS.  I am using a script supplied by [here](https://www.apalrd.net/posts/2023/pve_cloud/).

My current script is as such

```
#!/bin/bash

#Create template
#args:
# vm_id
# vm_name
# file name in the current directory
function create_template() {
    #Print all of the configuration
    echo "Creating template $2 ($1)"

    #Create new VM 
    #Feel free to change any of these to your liking
    qm create $1 --name $2 --ostype l26 
    #Set networking to default bridge
    qm set $1 --net0 virtio,bridge=vmbr0
    #Set display to serial
    qm set $1 --serial0 socket --vga serial0
    #Set memory, cpu, type defaults
    #If you are in a cluster, you might need to change cpu type
    qm set $1 --memory 1024 --cores 4 --cpu host
    #Set boot device to new file
    qm set $1 --scsi0 ${storage}:0,import-from="$(pwd)/$3",discard=on
    #Set scsi hardware as default boot disk using virtio scsi single
    qm set $1 --boot order=scsi0 --scsihw virtio-scsi-single
    #Enable Qemu guest agent in case the guest has it available
    qm set $1 --agent enabled=1,fstrim_cloned_disks=1
    #Add cloud-init device
    qm set $1 --ide2 ${storage}:cloudinit
    #Set CI ip config
    #IP6 = auto means SLAAC (a reliable default with no bad effects on non-IPv6 networks)
    #IP = DHCP means what it says, so leave that out entirely on non-IPv4 networks to avoid DHCP delays
    qm set $1 --ipconfig0 "ip6=auto,ip=dhcp"
    #Import the ssh keyfile
    # qm set $1 --sshkeys ${ssh_keyfile}
    #If you want to do password-based auth instaed
    #Then use this option and comment out the line above
    qm set $1 --cipassword password
    #Add the user
    qm set $1 --ciuser ${username}
    #Resize the disk to 8G, a reasonable minimum. You can expand it more later.
    #If the disk is already bigger than 8G, this will fail, and that is okay.
    qm disk resize $1 scsi0 8G

    #Make it a template
    qm template $1

    #Remove file when done
    rm $3
}


#Path to your ssh authorized_keys file
#Alternatively, use /etc/pve/priv/authorized_keys if you are already authorized
#on the Proxmox system
export ssh_keyfile=/root/id_rsa.pub
#Username to create on VM template
export username=root

#Name of your storage
export storage=main

#The images that I've found premade
#Feel free to add your own

## Debian
#Buster (10)
wget "https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/buster/latest/debian-10-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2"
create_template 900 "temp-debian-10" "debian-10-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2"
#Bullseye (11)
wget "https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/bullseye/latest/debian-11-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2"
create_template 901 "temp-debian-11" "debian-11-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2" 
#Bookworm (12 dailies - not yet released)
wget "https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/bookworm/daily/latest/debian-12-genericcloud-amd64-daily.qcow2"
create_template 902 "temp-debian-12-daily" "debian-12-genericcloud-amd64-daily.qcow2" 

## Ubuntu
#20.04 (Focal Fossa)
wget "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img"
create_template 910 "temp-ubuntu-20-04" "ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img" 
#22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)
wget "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/release/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img"
create_template 911 "temp-ubuntu-22-04" "ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img" 
#23.04 (Lunar Lobster) - daily builds
wget "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/lunar/current/lunar-server-cloudimg-amd64.img"
create_template 912 "temp-ubuntu-23-04-daily" "lunar-server-cloudimg-amd64.img"

## Fedora 37
#Image is compressed, so need to uncompress first
wget https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/37/Cloud/x86_64/images/Fedora-Cloud-Base-37-1.7.x86_64.raw.xz
xz -d -v Fedora-Cloud-Base-37-1.7.x86_64.raw.xz
create_template 920 "temp-fedora-37" "Fedora-Cloud-Base-37-1.7.x86_64.raw"

## CentOS Stream
#Stream 8
wget https://cloud.centos.org/centos/8-stream/x86_64/images/CentOS-Stream-GenericCloud-8-20220913.0.x86_64.qcow2
create_template 930 "temp-centos-8-stream" "CentOS-Stream-GenericCloud-8-20220913.0.x86_64.qcow2"
#Stream 9 (daily) - they don't have a 'latest' link?
wget https://cloud.centos.org/centos/9-stream/x86_64/images/CentOS-Stream-GenericCloud-9-20230123.0.x86_64.qcow2
create_template 931 "temp-centos-9-stream-daily" "CentOS-Stream-GenericCloud-9-20230123.0.x86_64.qcow2"
```

Now in order to try and install qemu on each device I am trying something like this before the template creation, but it fails.  So I am unsure if there is a better way to install on the VM and enable the qemu-agent?

```
    # Install and enable qemu-guest-agent based on the distribution
    case $2 in
        temp-debian-10 | temp-debian-11 | temp-debian-12-daily)
            qm set $1 --exec "apt update && apt install -y qemu-guest-agent"
            ;;
        temp-ubuntu-20-04 | temp-ubuntu-22-04 | temp-ubuntu-23-04-daily)
            qm set $1 --exec "apt update && apt install -y qemu-guest-agent"
            ;;
        temp-fedora-37)
            qm set $1 --exec "dnf install -y qemu-guest-agent && systemctl enable --now qemu-guest-agent"
            ;;
        temp-centos-8-stream | temp-centos-9-stream-daily)
            qm set $1 --exec "dnf install -y qemu-guest-agent && systemctl enable --now qemu-guest-agent"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unsupported distribution: $2"
            ;;
    esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it using a cloud-int file

`qm set $1 --cicustom "user=local:snippets/100.yaml"`

With the file looknig like so

```
#cloud-config
ssh_pwauth: true
disable_root: false
chpasswd:
  list: |
    root:password
  expire: false

write_files:
  - path: /etc/sudoers.d/cloud-init
    content: |
      Defaults !requiretty

package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - qemu-guest-agent

runcmd:
  - sed -i 's/^#PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e 's/^GSSAPIAuthentication yes/GSSAPIAuthentication no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e 's/^PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - systemctl restart sshd
  - systemctl enable qemu-guest-agent
  - systemctl start qemu-guest-agent
```